# How do I attach to an existing docker-machine (Azure)?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-machine

Say I use the following command to create a new Azure docker machine:

```
docker-machine create -d azure \
       --azure-subscription-id="$AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" \
       --azure-size=Standard_D14_v2 \
       --azure-subscription-cert="${PWD}/certs/mycert.pem" \
       --azure-location="East US" \
       my-azure-node
```

After this, I can see my-azure-node when I run `docker-machine ls`, ssh to it, and run any docker command I want on it.

But now I want a co-worker to be able to operate on that same running machine. So, once I pass `mycert.pem` to her (stupid question but can I even share this file with her?). How does she initializes docker-machine such that she will see the same machine when doing `docker-machine ls`, without trying to create a new one.

I basically want to have a single docker machine we share, and do that with the simplicity of docker-machine.

Comment: @dkarchmer: did you solve your problem ?  I have the same problem.

Comment: Not really but I believe the solution is using the generic driver. I ended up not having to solve the problem so I let it go. But I am fairly sure the answer is the ferocity driver https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/

Comment: Astonishingly this does not seem to be supported yet. See: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1328. Here is a tool that might get you going for now: https://www.npmjs.com/package/machine-share